# Graphics glitch - checkered pattern in Chrome

Tags: hardware, google-chrome, graphics

I've had this MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) for a while now, but today it glitched out with huge green fields in all apps.

After a reboot I see this checkered black/green glitch pattern in Google Chrome on some sites, in some "sizes". Basically if I resize the browser window the glitch goes away, but if I resize it too much it comes back.

Happens both on the internal and on external display.

I am hoping this is a software glitch, but I am afraid it's my graphics card. Would be very grateful if someone knows the answer.

Here's the stackoverflow logo with the glitch:

[image: StackOverflow logo glitched]

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is to turn off the `GPU rasterization` option in `chrome://flags`. It can solve the graphics glitch issue but definitely not the best solution. Need to wait for Chrome's official patches.

[image]